# How would I get an update mirror to use its mirror folder for an update

Tags: apt, updates, mirrors

I have a trusty mirror file structure mounted from an external volume.  What I would like to do is to spin up a new, blank VM, and have it update, upgrade and install an ftp server to serve the mirror to other VMs.

I can't modify `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use `ftp://` before the server is installed.

Is there a way to get apt-get to use the mounted volume?   Will `sources.list` support `file://` protocol?

---

Using the answer below, I mounted the mirror directory as a shared folder, and ran the following on the VM;

```
sed -i -e s#http://archive.ubuntu.com#file:///srv/ftp#g \
       -e s#http://security.ubuntu.com#file:///srv/ftp#g \
       /etc/apt/sources.list 
apt-get update 
apt-get -y upgrade 
apt-get -y install proftpd-basic 
apt-get -y autoremove
# configure /etc/proftpd/conf.d/anonymous.conf
service proftpd restart
```

Other VMs refer to the newly minted mirror for their updates;

```
sed -i -e s#http://archive.ubuntu.com#ftp://mirror-vm#g \
       -e s#http://security.ubuntu.com#ftp://mirror-vm#g \
       /etc/apt/sources.list 
apt-get update 
apt-get -y upgrade 
apt-get -y install yada-yada-yada 
apt-get -y autoremove
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite get how you intend to install the `ftp` server, but `sources.list` does support the `file://` 'protocol'.

To add a deb package to your `sources.list` file:

```
deb file:///path/to/directory /
```